# Jquery to Change z-index of a specific thumbnail

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, thumbnails

I tried this another way a while ago to no avail. I'm trying to change the img of thumbnail when clicked. right now I have a hover code that fades one div over another when moused over. I tried adding .click function to that code, but it made the whole thing whacky. Sooo, I'm getting somewhere with this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Thumb1").click(function () {
        $("#hidden").hide().html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/38581363?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1" width="508" height="286" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>').fadeIn(4e3);
        $("#leftsidePlayer").text("This is some text on the consulting video!")
        $("img.b").css({zIndex: 11});
    });
```

that is the code for one thumbnail. There are 4. It works but its controlling all the thumbnail in the the wrapping div. How can I make it so it jut works for the one I'm clicking on?

this is the css I have

```
div.fadehover {
position:relative;
}

img.a {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:10;
}

img.b {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:5;
}
```

I know it most likely has something to do with using (this) but I am still learning.

any help greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line `$("img.b").css({zIndex: 11});` with what follows.

```
$(this).css({zIndex: 11});
```

That way you'll change the z-index only for the element you clicked on.

Comment: Well, you didn't provide your full code, did you? I meant to replace the line `$("img.b").css({zIndex: 11});` with what I wrote. That way you'll change the z-index only for the element you clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your markup? I wouldn't do z-index for this. May as well just fadeIn() and hide():

Markup -

```
<div class='thumb'>
  <img src=''/>
  <img src='' style='display:none;'/>
</div>
```

jQuery -

```
$(".thumb").click(function ( e ) {
  var children = $( this ).children();
  var first-thumb = th.slice(0,1);
  var second-thumb = th.slice(1,2);

  if( first-thumb.is( ':visible' ) )
  {
    first-thumb.hide().next().fadeIn();
  }
  else
  {
    second-thumb.hide().prev().fadeIn();
  }    
});
```